# PHP Style foreach loops in C++

Tags: php, c++, templates, foreach

Is it possible to implement this using templates preferably in a way that would work with vectors and arrays, but especially vectors.

- The main functionality, used in PHP as:

  ```
  foreach(objects as object)
  { object=this*that; }
  ```
- It would be nice to have the alternative usage as well if possible:

  ```
  foreach(objects as key => object)
  { object=formula(key); }
  ```

`=>` is non essential. Templates aside, **any** technique, would be acceptable given this format.

Comment: Just a note, I have no problems whatsoever designing or making a foreach function. The styling is what I'm focused on. I have seen some pretty fancy syntactic sugar out there for similar problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++0x supports [range-based for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Range-based_for-loop):

```
for (T& object : objects)
   object = this * that;
```

but not many compilers support this yet (only gcc 4.6 have it AFAIK). Still, you could use `std::for_each` with a lambda function like:

```
std::for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](T& object) {
   object = this * that;
});
```

If you don't like C++0x, you could use [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/foreach.html) like

```
BOOST_FOREACH(T& object, objects) {
  object = this * that;
}
```

---

For a `std::vector`, there is no built-in support for the `=>` form. You need to keep the index yourself.

```
int key = 0;
for (T& object : objects) {
   object = formula(key);
   ++ key;
}

key = 0;
std::for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [&key](T& object) {
   object = formula(key);
   ++ key;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/foreach.html).

STL and Boost both provide `foreach`.

Comment: The STL version wont fit, I especially need to have a code block following: `foreach(){ ....... }` Any clues to how Boost does this?

Comment: @Garet Claborn: I haven't researched it my self, but you can access all of the source and read the documentation to better understand how it functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a foreach statement in C++, you can take a look to Qt source, they have an implementations that works with a preprocessor directive (Macro) and looks something like this:

```
foreach(element,collection)
{
  //some code to work with element.
}
```

Comment: Will look to see how they implement this. Thanks.

Comment: If you'd like to use it in your project out of the box, you can simply use the QtCore module from Qt, which will add all the common utilities without the overwhelming of the GUI and other modules.

Answer (score 1):

C++0x introduces syntax for iterating over any container that has `begin()` and `end()` iterators, which includes any STL container such as `vector`:

```
for (auto& object : objects)
    object = this * that;
```

You can also use `begin()` and `end()` explicitly and dereference the iterator yourself, or use `std::for_each()` with a lambda:

```
#include <algorithm>
std::for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](Object& object) -> void {
    object = this * that;
});
```

Comment: I'll never get used to these lambdas. They look like piles of digital vomit.

Comment: @David: Well, the syntax is punctuation-heavy and ridiculously explicit, but what else would you expect from C++? Besides, it had to be unambiguous in the context of the already too complex grammar.